# Ошибка скрипта в версии PHP 5.3

Tags: php

Есть класс для постинга в вк, главное в PHP 5.3.2 выдаёт ошибку на строке 15:

> `syntax error, unepected '[', epecting ')'`

а в версии PHP 5.4 ошибок нет. В чем может быть ошибка?

Проверяю тут - http://ru.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/

```
namespace BW;
class Vkontakte
{
const VERSION = '5.5';
private $appId;
private $secret;
private $scope = array();
private $redirect_uri;
private $responceType = 'code';
private $accessToken;
public function __construct(array $config)
{
if (isset($config['access_token'])) {
$this->setAccessToken(json_encode(['access_token' => $config['access_token']])); //ошибка тут
}
if (isset($config['app_id'])) {
$this->setAppId($config['app_id']);
}
if (isset($config['secret'])) {
$this->setSecret($config['secret']);
}
if (isset($config['scopes'])) {
$this->setScope($config['scopes']);
}
if (isset($config['redirect_uri'])) {
$this->setRedirectUri($config['redirect_uri']);
}
if (isset($config['response_type'])) {
$this->setResponceType($config['response_type']);
}
}
public function getUserId()
{
return $this->accessToken->user_id;
}
public function setAppId($appId)
{
$this->appId = $appId;
return $this;
}
public function getAppId()
{
return $this->appId;
}
public function setSecret($secret)
{
$this->secret = $secret;
return $this;
}
public function getSecret()
{
return $this->secret;
}
public function setScope(array $scope)
{
$this->scope = $scope;
return $this;
}
public function getScope()
{
return $this->scope;
}
public function setRedirectUri($redirect_uri)
{
$this->redirect_uri = $redirect_uri;
return $this;
}
public function getRedirectUri()
{
return $this->redirect_uri;
}
public function setResponceType($responceType)
{
$this->responceType = $responceType;
return $this;
}
public function getResponceType()
{
return $this->responceType;
}
public function getLoginUrl()
{
return 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize'
. '?client_id=' . urlencode($this->getAppId())
. '&scope=' . urlencode(implode(',', $this->getScope()))
. '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($this->getRedirectUri())
. '&response_type=' . urlencode($this->getResponceType())
. '&v=' . urlencode(self::VERSION);
}
public function isAccessTokenExpired()
{
return time() > $this->accessToken->created + $this->accessToken->expires_in;
}
public function authenticate($code = NULL)
{
$code = $code ? $code : $_GET['code'];
$url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token'
. '?client_id=' . urlencode($this->getAppId())
. '&client_secret=' . urlencode($this->getSecret())
. '&code=' . urlencode($code)
. '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($this->getRedirectUri());
$token = $this->curl($url);
$data = json_decode($token);
$data->created = time();
$token = json_encode($data);
$this->setAccessToken($token);
return $this;
}
public function setAccessToken($token)
{
$this->accessToken = json_decode($token);
return $this;
}
public function getAccessToken()
{
return json_encode($this->accessToken);
}
public function api($method, array $query = array())
{
$parameters = array();
foreach ($query as $param => $value) {
$q = $param . '=';
if (is_array($value)) {
$q .= urlencode(implode(',', $value));
} else {
$q .= urlencode($value);
}
$parameters[] = $q;
}
$q = implode('&', $parameters);
if (count($query) > 0) {
$q .= '&';
}
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/' . $method . '?' . $q . 'access_token=' . $this->accessToken->access_token;
$result = json_decode($this->curl($url));
return $result;
}
protected function curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$result) {
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
if (isset($errno) && isset($error)) {
throw new \Exception($error, $errno);
}
return $result;
}
public function postToPublic($publicID, $text, $fullServerPathToImage)
{
$types = getimagesize($fullServerPathToImage);
$type = $types['mime'];
if ($type ==  'image/jpeg' || $type ==  'image/png') {
$response = $this->api('photos.getWallUploadServer', [
'group_id' => $publicID,
]);
$uploadURL = $response->response->upload_url;
$output = [];
$datab = array('photo' => '@'.$fullServerPathToImage);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datab);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($output);
$response = $this->api('photos.saveWallPhoto', [
'group_id' => $publicID,
'photo' => $response->photo,
'server' => $response->server,
'hash' => $response->hash,
]);
if ($tags) {
$text .= "\n\n";
}
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
$text .= ' #' . str_replace(' ', '_', $tag);
}
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
$response = $this->api('wall.post',
[
'owner_id' => -$publicID,
'from_group' => 1,
'attachments' => "{$response->response[0]->id}",
]);
return true;
}
if ($type ==  'image/gif') {$response = $this->api('docs.getUploadServer', [
]);
$uploadURL = $response->response->upload_url;
$output = [];
$datab = array('file' => '@'.$fullServerPathToImage);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datab);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($output);
$response2 = $this->api('docs.save', [
'file' => $response->file,
'title' => 'site.ru',
'tags' => 'site.ru'
]);
if ($tags) {
$text .= "\n\n";
}
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
$text .= ' #' . str_replace(' ', '_', $tag);
}
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
$response = $this->api('wall.post',
[
'owner_id' => -$publicID,
'from_group' => 1,
'message' => "$text",
'attachments' => 'doc'.$response2->response[0]->owner_id.'_'.$response2->response[0]->did,
]);
return true;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Придется либо использовать `5.4` либо заменять  у всех массивов с `[ ]` на `array()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский уже сменил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

До версии 5.4 PHP не поддерживал короткий синтакс для массивов.

```
[]; // PHP 5.4+ array
array(); // PHP 5.3 array
```